# Convergence of algorithm (bisection, fixed point, Newton's method, secant method)

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, algorithms, fixed-point-theorems, bisection

Consider solving the equation $\exp(x) - x - 1 = 0$.

It is obvious that $x^* = 0$ is a solution of the equation. Suppose you don't know this and you would like to *approximate* $x^*$ numerically by one of the following four methods. Which method will lead to a convergent algorithm for approximating $x^*$?

Why are the others not suitable?

The four methods are *bisection method*, *fixed point iteration*, *Newton's Method*, and *Secant method*.

Attempt: I tried each method on the equation but I have found that each converges which I know is not correct.

For fixed point iteration, I put the equation in the form $x = \exp(x) - 1$.

I don't know where to start in terms of the "inverval" to begin with i.e. with bisection the first thing I do is try $x=0$ and I get that it is the root. So am I done? Is bisection method the "correct" method in this case?

Comment: $0$ doesn't solve that.  Do you have some signs wrong?

Comment: or did you leave out some parentheses?

Comment: I had a sign wrong in the original equation. Fixed it.

Comment: If you can compute the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) it's $-W(-\exp(-1))-1$ ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\exp(x)-1-x=\frac12x^2\left(1+\frac13x+\frac1{12}x^2+...\right)
$$
has a minimum in $x=0$ and behaves locally like $\frac12 x^2$.

[image: plot of the function]

Note that you pretend to not know the root. Starting the one of the methods at the point $x=0$ has thus to be considered extremely unlikely.

- *bisection method:* fails before the first step as all function values away from $x=0$ have positive sign, no interval with sign alteration exists,
- *fixed point iteration:* depends on the iteration function,
- *Newton's Method:* converges linearly, and
- *Secant method:* Convergence, as always, depends on the initial pair. If the secant becomes horizontal, the iteration can move far away from zero. It might recover or it might oscillate chaotically.

Comment: Rather than write out my own answer, I'll just add that for the suggested fixed-point iteration of $h(x) = e^x - 1$, we have $x < h(x)$ for all $x$ and $x<0 \iff h(x)<0$, so this converges for $x<0$ and diverges for $x>0$.